# how to center gridlayout in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-styles

i am trying to implement recyler view with grid layout but i have problem to center the items, the problem is with the items with the small text i try to center all here is my xml

here is 2 picture of the recyler view one is good and one is not

https://ibb.co/wMtX1Yr
https://ibb.co/8gHNmZT

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_img"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_file"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:id="@+id/file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem before, and I solve it by making the View holder width `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.
 and I set spanCount in `GridLayoutManager` to 2 or whatever you want.